# Ambiguous tag: [word]

Tags: discussion, retagging

The [word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) tag is meaningless and subject to abuse.  Its tag wiki is not helpful either:

> The tag is for the question of any kind but related to a 'word' in general.

English.SE has no questions tagged [[word]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word).  Instead, there are more specific tags such as [word-choice], [word-usage], and [meaning].

There are currently 64 questions tagged with [word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word).  Most of them appear to be questions about either [word-choice] or [meaning].  It's not too late to retag these questions before the situation gets out of hand.  I think it's worth harmonizing the tags with English.SE to facilitate migration of questions between sites.

Comment: IMO, [tag:word] ought to be burninated (i.e. removed from use and prevented from ever being added again).

Comment: @Martha Why don't you propose that in an answer?

Comment: I agree with the burnination. I think the tag [word] is unnecessary at all since we already have another similar tag [vocabulary], which, evidently, also exists on ELU (English.SE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done! I passed this along to the SE Community Team and they have burninated the tag.

We now have 45 questions tagged [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), though, so we should start working on fixing that problem by tagging them appropriately.

Comment: Down to 30! :-)

Comment: Is it just me, or is [tag:word] still an existing tag? I just suggested edits to remove it from two questions.

Answer (score 10):

Burninate [word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word).

> IMO, [word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) ought to be burninated (i.e. removed from use and prevented from ever being added again). –  [Martha](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/50/martha) 12 hours ago

(I'm turning Martha's comment into an answer so it can be voted on or accepted.)

Answer (score 0):

...just tell me what should the more beginning English Language Learners tag their posts when they have no clue how to tag them - when they are on level of 'My name is Tom. What is your name?' - and just don't know any grammar terms to put in the tag fields. True that tag is useless, and any question with it should be retagged, but then, if not this one, then what?

(personally, I believe we should just allow untagged posts...)

Comment: Clueless beginners will put a random tag on their question initially. Hopefully some other user will improve the tags on the question. That still doesn't justify the existence of [word].